# Unity C# 3dCollisionTrigger not working as intended

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a script that deals damage to enemies. It is attached to a weapon with a box collider that is a trigger. Whenever the weapon hits a certain game object, I get the health from it, and subtract it by the damage. The problem is that not only the enemy object gets hit, but the weapon object gets hit.

I have no idea why this is happening. I don’t understand collision in unity completely. From what I know, it should work.

EDIT:
Fixed it myself after 10000 hours,i relocated everything with attacking in a new Object on the main object an now its working.

WHAT IF LEARNED:
Dont do attacking and taking damage with the same Object.

Code:

```cs
public class MeleeAttackScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Range = 1.0f;
    public float AttackSpeed = 1.2f;
    public float AttackCooldown = 0f;
    public float Damage = 5f;

    bool Collision = false;
    BoxCollider RangeCollider;
    Collider HitObject;

    public void Awake()
    {
        RangeCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
        RangeCollider.size = new Vector3(1, 1, Range);
        RangeCollider.center = new Vector3(0, 0.00001f, (RangeCollider.size.z+1)/2);
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (AttackCooldown > 0)
        {
            AttackCooldown -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Mathf.Clamp(AttackCooldown, 0, (1 / AttackSpeed)) == 0 && Collision && HitObject.gameObject.tag == "Object")
        {
            Attack();
            Collision = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerStay (Collider collider)
    {
        if (collider.GetComponent<Collider>().GetType() == typeof(CapsuleCollider))
        {
            Debug.Log(collider.name);
            HitObject = collider;
            Collision = true;
        }
    }

    public void Attack()
    {

            HitObject.gameObject.GetComponent<LifePointScript>().CurrentLifePoints -= Damage;






        AttackCooldown = 1 / (AttackSpeed);
    }


}
```

Image:
[Visualized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EftBQ.png)

Comment: I did not understand the problem. So, the weapon is attacking the player as well?

Comment: @ken y it gets selfdamage

Answer (score 3):

Set different [`layers`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) on your objects, then in the physics settings, disable index in the collision matrix that corresponds to itself. That way, a collider that is layered on the same layer will not collide with itself.

First, select the layer drop down on any object
[image: Select the drop down]

Next, create a new layer

[image: New Layer]

After creating the new layer and assigning it to both objects, go to the physics settings in your project **Edit->Project Settings->Physics**.

At the bottom of this settings tab, you will find the collision matrix. Find the intersection between your new layer and itself, then disable that collision layer.
[image: Collision Matrix]

Comment: Using layers for this limits you to 32 objects (including the Unity builtin layers)

Comment: wont work, because both objects are clones from each other and they just couldnt attack each other anymore

further more ive got it to work, but it only worked when the damage was set to 0 and i manually set the damage to its old value(5) in the inspector and it didnt work, when i set it to 5 with a script, i have no idea why this is the case :()

Answer (score 0):

Your initial approach is ok but there is one tiny detail you are missing and thats why both the enemy and player are getting damaged (and the box itself).

Your box collider checks for a collision... fine... but... both the player and enemy have a collision (and your box collider).

You must differentiate them. An easy way to do this could be by comparing the tag of the object you are colliding with, or the name of the object, both approachs should work.

In other words, in your on trigger stay you could compare if the tag of the object in the trigger is an enemy, damage it. In case there is someone else in the trigger (the player for example) it will just ignore it, since its tag or gameobject name is not "enemy".

Comment: that wont work if the objects are the same, what they are, because they are the same Unit

further more ive got it to work, but it only worked when the damage was set to 0 and i manually set the damage to its old value(5) in the inspector and it didnt work, when i set it to 5 with a script, i have no idea why this is the case :()

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact Hierarchy but in general using Layers as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67729468/7111561) has a big drawback: It limits you to the amount of available Layers (32 inlcuding 8 Unity builtin Layers).

Instead you could have a set of colliders you simply ignore via [`Physics.IgnoreCollision`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.IgnoreCollision.html)

and do something like e.g.

```
// reference via the Inspector
[SerializeField] private Collider[] ignoreColliders;

private void Awake()
{
    ...

    foreach(var collider in ignoreColliders)
    {
        Physics.IgnoreCollision(RangeCollider, collider);
    }
}
```

so any `MeleeAttackScript` instance can ignore it's own according player object's colliders.

Comment: didnt work, it still gets damage, can be, that i did something wrong, but that didnt fixed it

further more ive got it to work, but it only worked when the damage was set to 0 and i manually set the damage to its old value(5) in the inspector and it didnt work, when i set it to 5 with a script, i have no idea why this is the case :()